# SQL - find all the rows where the values are the same, or next biggest

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony

I have a table where in one column I have lot of Int -values from x to y and it kinda loops. The values go from lowest to highest, but start again after awhile. Values look like this:

```
TableRow:
2
5
10
15
..
30
40
50
// And here it begins again:
2
5
10
..
// And again:
2
5
10
// And the sequence may change too:
3
6
10
```

I would like to search for values that are the same, or **next** biggest. I.e. If I have a search value of 6, I would like the search to return rows where this value is: 10, 10, 10, and so on. Not the fives, but the bigger ones. But I **don't** want **all** of the bigger ones after the value! Only the **next** one. If I have a search value of 1.9 or less, the search should return all the 2 -values.
How do I form an sql that will accomplish this?

PS: Symfony "createQueryBuilder" -example for this would be great, but not necessary! :)

**Edit:** (More info)
This table has other columns as well, 10 others to be exact, including id-column as well. No timestamps though.

Comment: Rows have no order in SQL, so you just have a column of numbers.

Comment: Is there also an id column, or timestamp, or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the value you are looking for using a subquery.  Then you can get the matching rows:

```
select t.*
from table t
where value = (select min(value)
               from table t
               where value >= 6
              );
```

Comment: Works nicely! Thanks a bunch!